# Read list of packages installed on a LimaCharlie Sensor using Python limacharlie library

Tags: python

I have written a Python script that gets all LimaCharlie sensors. However I want to also get the packages, and not just the sensors data.

This is a screenshot of the list of packages in [LimaCharlie.io](https://LimaCharlie.io) that I am trying to get:

[image]

This is the script I have now that gets a list of sensors:

**requirements.txt**

```
limacharlie
```

**lc_sensor_list.py**

```
import limacharlie


def lc_sensor_list():
    oid: str = "a-1-2-3-d"
    api_key: str = "1-2-3-x-h"

    # Connect to LimaCharlie
    manager = limacharlie.Manager(oid=oid, secret_api_key=api_key)

    # List of sensors
    sensors_list: dict = manager.exportSensorList()
    print(f"sensors_list={sensors_list}")

    # Write assets to file
    f = open(f"sensors_list.json", "w")
    f.write(sensors_list)
    f.close()

# - Main start ----------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
    lc_sensor_list()
```

**This gives me a list of sensors:**

```
{
    "sensors": {
        "x-y-z-a-b": {
            "alive": 1703377457,
            "arch": "usp_adapter",
        .....
        },
        "a-b-9-v-b": {
            "alive": 1703377457,
            "arch": "usp_adapter",
        .....
        }
    }
}
```